# Is there a way to easily blunt a corner vertex into three vertices?

Tags: vertices, bevel

I want to take the pointedness out my corners by blunting them.  i want turn the corner vertices into 3.  Imagine my drawing to be a corner of a cube...

[image]

[image]

I tried to bevel using CTRL-SHIFT-B but it changes so much of the surrounding geometry.. too many side effects for what I want.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bevel tool can do exactly what you want, just make sure "vertex only" is enabled and "segments" is set to 1:

[image: bevel tool settings]

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> works fine. But you need to make sure, your surrounding geometry has good topology. If you bevel the vertex of a non-planar face for example, the silhouette of your object may chance dramatically.

[image: beveling non-planar faces]

First two bevels on planar faces, the third one is non-planar.